# Format usb flash drive 8gb to be bootable

Tags: windows, installation

I was trying to write windows xp image on my transcend jetflash 8gb, but got an error in the middle of the format process.

### PeToUSB Error!

FormatEx Error[11]: An Error Occurred Formating the Drive.

Is there any way to make 8 gb flash drive bootable, e.g. install windows from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the later version of [PeToUSB 3.0.0.8](http://eaz.nm.ru/download/PeToUSB_3.0.0.8.zip).

This version can format more than 4GB, while your version probably can't.

Source: [PE2USB Boot Windows From FlashDrive](http://ezyuzin.livejournal.com/2729.html).